# Canva: How to color specific part of the element

Tags: canva

I have this very basic design for letter. I'm trying to find the way to color the part of the feather that overlaps the inner white body a different color.

[image]

I tried duplicating the feather and crop to the specific part, but the problem is that the crop doesn't give an option for different shapes.
I also tried frames, but they only work with photos and videos.
I'm not sure how else should I approach to get the desired effect.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not asked, but vector drawing software (=such as Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Designer) users would make a clipping mask, for ex just the white area shape for the differently colored duplicate of you feather and layer it on the top. Template based online layout tools may also allow that approach. Check if clipping masks are allowed.

Comment: @user287001 Unfortunatelly canva doesn't have a clipping tool but has something similar. It's called frames. Problem is that they only work with photos and videos and not elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've came up with some solution, but it's not elegant at all. Since frames take on the photo I took a snapshot of that part trying to match the height and the width of the frame as much as I could and then upload that snapped image and put it into the fram. It's not excatly perfect, you could see not every part lines up well, but it's as close as I got [image]

Obviously it's a tedious work if you want to try another color for the specific part.
So not the best, but will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am assuming that you want to change the border color? please correct me if I am wrong

Take a Rectangle shape behind and try giving a stroke and then increase the size of the stroke and then give a color accordingly.

[image: Reference Video]

Comment: I'm not really sure how that will achieve the effect I am looking for. I tried it, but it won't really get me there. Thanks a lot for the suggestion tho :)

Comment: No sorry, probably I phrased it wrong. Not a border color, but the color of the specific part of feather.